# digitalocean add ssh key to droplet not working

Tags: digital-ocean

I have got all available ssh key but it is not added into droplet.

```java
List<Key> availableKeys = new ArrayList<Key>();
    Keys keys;
    int page = 0;
    do {
        page += 1;
        keys = digitalOceanClient.getAvailableKeys(page);
        availableKeys.addAll(keys.getKeys());
    } while (keys.getMeta().getTotal() > availableKeys.size());

    System.out.println(" availableKeys ::  "+availableKeys);

    droplet.setKeys(availableKeys);
```

Answer (score 1):

DigitalOcean does not provide an API endpoint to add an ssh-key to an existing droplet.  The API will allow you to specify a key when you create a new droplet.

Once your droplet has been created you will have to add additional keys manually by adding them to `~/ssh/authorized_keys`